# URL Path depth reduction .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We now reduce the depth of paths:

from https://example.com/en/products/i/dance-show-blabla/STUYXhzEYT

to https://example.com/en/dance-show-blabla/STUYXhzEYT

So, we using this htacces code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)$ index.php?siteModule=$2

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)$ index.php?siteModule=$2&pageController=$3

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)$ index.php?siteModule=$2&pageController=$3&pageData=$4 [L]
```

Can it be solved more easily? Merge from 3 rule to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can correctly interpret empty variables, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?$ index.php?siteModule=$1&pageController=$2&pageData=$3 [L]
```